# React Native How get property name array from a variable string

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I try to get a specific array index with a variable like this :

```
var test = 'category_'+this.state.idCategorie // here = category_2
console.log(CategoriesCardsData[test]) // return undefined
console.log(CategoriesCardsData['category_2']) // works
```

But if i try to get it from my variable test, i have an undefined.

```
class CategoriesList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          CardsData: CategoriesCardsData, 
          newDataCards: [], 
          idCategorie: props.navigation.state.params.idCategorie
        }
    }
}

_test() {
  var test = 'category_'+this.state.idCategorie
  console.log(CategoriesCardsData[test])
}

render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main_container}>
                {{this._test()}}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

And my CardsData :

```
        export default CategoriesCardsData = {'categorie_1': categorie_1(), 'categorie_2': categorie_2()}
    
    function categorie_1() {
      return [{
          ...
        }]
    }
    
    same for function categorie_2, but i cant post, dont know why have an error with stackoverflow...
```

Component where navigation from, i send my idCategorie here

```
            <FlatList
              ...

                  return(
                    // i send my idcategorie here
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.categorie} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Categories", {idCategorie:item.id})}>
                            <Text style={styles.CategoriesText}>{item.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>

                  )
                }
              }

            />
```

Comment: If your `this.state.idCategorie` is actually a number, then this should work. Post a minimum reproducible demo in order to be able to help.

Comment: i have edit my post with my code for explain

Comment: I see that the `idCategorie` in state is dependant on the navigation state. Is it possible that `console.log` is sometimes working and sometimes not ? Also post code of Component where you are navigating from.

Comment: its ok i have edit and add it. For the console i don't know i have test a lot of time, and i dont see  problem.
But for my var test i have test too : var test = 'category_'+2 that dosnt work too, so i dont think the problem is my navigation state

Comment: Got it. Your code seems completely correct. However the details are not sufficient to answer this. Use https://snack.expo.io/ to create a reproducible demo.

Comment: I have do it on snack.expo.io that works fine ... Don't understand why that dosnt work on mine.

Comment: do a `console.log(this.state.idCategorie)` at the start of `_test` function. what is coming ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232353/discussion-between-nisanth-reddy-and-ygg69).

Comment: i have found the problem, i imported my data on the other page, i need to import to the current page to do it